# Inverse text in cell with SPLIT and ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, split, transpose, array-formulas

I have a column with names like this:

```
Doe, John
Smith, Sam
King, Martin Luther
***
```

The intent is to put inverse the names and remove the comma. If I use the formula:
`=REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(" "; SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(G14;" "));SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(G14;" ")));0)); ",$";)`

It works and transforms the name from G14 (Doe, John) to John Doe. The issue is that this is done on over 400 values that change on a day to day basis, so I tried putting it all in an arrayformula:
`=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(not(ISBLANK(G14:G)); REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(" "; SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(G14:G;" "));SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(G14:G;" ")));0)); ",$";)); "error"))`

Whenever I do this, all the cells retrieve errors, cause by

> Function SPLIT parameter 1 value should be non-empty.

I have looked through some answers with the same error, but I cannot figure out how to properly apply them to my case.

`=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(not(ISBLANK(G14:G)); REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(" "; SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(G14:G;" "));SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(G14:G;" ")));0)); ",$";)); "error"))`

Comment: the shared formula converts `King, Martin Luther` into `Luther Martin King`; Is that intended or should it be `Martin Luther King`?!

Comment: Good spot. I was so focused on the array that I completely missed that. It should be `Martin Luther King`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this if its going to be fixed 2 parameters alike `Last name, First name`:

```
=map(A:A,lambda(z,if(z="",,let(Σ,split(z,", ",0),index(Σ,,2)&" "&index(Σ,,1)))))
```

this version will work for dynamic number of parameters `Last name, Middle Name1, Middle Name2, First name`...

```
=map(A:A,lambda(z,if(z="",,let(Σ,split(z,", ",0),join(" ",sort(tocol(Σ),sequence(counta(Σ)),0))))))
```

[image]